# Is it possible to automate the conversion of ODBC to DB2 stages in Datastage 11.7.4?

Tags: datastage

We want to convert our jobs that are currently using the ODBC stages to use DB2 stage. We have a lot of jobs like this. Is it possible to automate this conversion somehow? I found this link but this specific case is not supported. [Rapid Job Update Tool for IBM InfoSphere Information Server DataStage jobs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rapid-job-update-tool-ibm-infosphere-information-server-datastage-jobs)

Any links or helpful tips to achieve this?

Comment: Looking at the list on the page you linked, I'd say your case should be suppoirted. There is support for the DB2 Connector as well as for the ODBC stage. And they also provide a download for the tool fitting to your DataStage version. I'd say just try it by exporting some jobs to a test project and try to convert them there.

Comment: but only ODBC-->Oracle is supported

Comment: Did you try hopping via oracle connector? It seems that ODBC -> Oracle is supported and also Oracle -> DB2 is supported. The tool is also using xml files to specify the connectors. I assume one could dive deeper into that and try to add an ODBC to DB2 path, but I'd rather try the 3-way solution, since the tool will left you with a todo list of unsolved jobs anyways.

Comment: Since I think this is an interesting topic, please let us know how if and how you solved it by answering your own question, later. :)